# CSS - Image height won't scale with width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Earlier I was pointed out how to achieve a certain layout I wanted to have for my page. However, this messes with my image height. As far as I understand, `height: auto;` should set the height to right proportion when a certain `width` is set.

Here's my code:

```
.floatingImage {
        width: 50px;
        height: auto;
    }

#floatingImageContainer {
    background-color: red;
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

<body>
    <div id = "floatingImageContainer">
        <img src = "images\miniImages\1.jpg" class = "floatingImage"></img>
        <img src = "images\miniImages\2.jpg" class = "floatingImage"></img>
        <img src = "images\miniImages\3.jpg" class = "floatingImage"></img>
        <img src = "images\miniImages\4.jpg" class = "floatingImage"></img>
        <img src = "images\miniImages\5.jpg" class = "floatingImage"></img>
        <img src = "images\miniImages\6.jpg" class = "floatingImage"></img>
    </div>
</body>
```

My guess is that it's got to do with the `display` property or maybe the `flex-wrap`, but that was the solution for my last problem and I'm not entirely sure yet how it could effect my image height... haven't added a margin in the screenshot, however that wouldn't change the height.

here's a screenshot of the issue:
[what the hell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMAjB.png)

Thank you in advance!

New problem:
[image: I don't know anymore...]

Comment: `<img>` does not have a closing tag

Comment: what exactly is the new problem?

Comment: The images are really far apart height-wise

Comment: try looking at the elements in your devtools to figure out if it's a margin, padding, the flex-container or something else

Comment: Tried it... It's not the margin, I can't highlight anything when hovering between the images in Chrome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

> align-items: center

on the container to prevent it from stretching its children.

```css
.floatingImage {
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
}

#floatingImageContainer {
  background-color: red;
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="floatingImageContainer">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" class="floatingImage"/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" class="floatingImage"/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" class="floatingImage"/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" class="floatingImage"/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" class="floatingImage"/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" class="floatingImage"/>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Today, **you**, sir are truly my personal hero.
Why does that work? What even prevented it from working before?

Comment: @KonstiLackner because by default they are stretched when using flexbox https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items

Comment: I think the flex-styling is more intended to style the items based on the container instead of themself

Comment: Any idea why the top margin seems to be so big when the screen gets smaller? Shouldn't it just be 10px?

Comment: I'd drop the code `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: center; align-items: center;`it is overkill just to center some images. Use `text-align: center; font-size: 0`.

Comment: My head hurts as well ... I can't drop the code, your suggestion doesn't work for what I'm trying to do :/ Check my last question to see the specifics.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `align-items` with an appropriate setting to the container for the `auto` height to work, for example `align-items: flex-start;`. Otherwise the items will be stretched to full height of the container by default:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.floatingImage {
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
}

#floatingImageContainer {
  background-color: red;
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div id="floatingImageContainer">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x500" class="floatingImage">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="floatingImage">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="floatingImage">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x400" class="floatingImage">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" class="floatingImage">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x350" class="floatingImage">
</div>
```

BTW, as mentioned in the comments: Closing `</img>` tags are invalid HTML - erase them...

Comment: Thank you very much! And yeah, I will erase the closing tags immediately!

Comment: Any idea why the top margin seems to be so big when the screen gets smaller? Shouldn't it just be 10px?

Comment: @KonstiLackner add also `align-content:flex-start`

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "top margin" (?)

Comment: well the images appear really far apart top to bottom - wise, while the margin between left and right sides fits.I'll add a screenshot to the question!

Comment: Might be due to the `height` setting of `#floatingImageContainer` (I don't know the rest of your code, so it's hard to tell)

Comment: Yes, after seeing the screenshot I am pretty sure that's it (the wrapped lines are pulled apart). You might want to decrease the container height (or make it auto) and wrap another container around it to keep the background color for the whole page.

Comment: HI! Didn't see his yesterday. Thank you very much, that worked like a charm!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `display: flex` to center the images horizontally which I am guessing was your last issue to fix, just use `display: block` and `text-align: center`. This will not mess with the images.

Also, I recommend setting image widths inside the actual `<img>` tag, setting the width property inside the tag and with no height will do the exact same as using CSS `height: auto`. I recommend this because for one it helps with arbitrary user agents(i.e. speech browsers), and relaying the correct aspect ratio for them. These will not normally be able to read the CSS. In addition, this allows the browsers to size the images even before the CSS and images resources are loaded. Not supplying, a width attribute in the image tag will cause the browser to render it as 0x0 until the browser can size.

Here is a working example:

```css
#floatingImageContainer {
  background-color: red;
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div id="floatingImageContainer">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" width="50" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" width="50" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" width="50" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" width="50" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" width="50" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" width="50" />
</div>
```